# hide a specific div id contents using css?

Tags: html, css

I was attempting to modify jellyfin to help a reddit user that wanted the trailers tab removed with js and html with css modifications and came across something that should be easy (with css) but I cannot work it out.

I have this code:

```html
<div id="moviesPage" data-role="page" data-dom-cache="true" class="page libraryPage backdropPage collectionEditorPage pageWithAbsoluteTabs withTabs" data-backdroptype="movie">
  <div class="pageTabContent" id="moviesTab" data-index="0">
    <div class="flex align-items-center justify-content-center flex-wrap-wrap padded-top padded-left padded-right padded-bottom">
      <div class="paging"></div> <button is="paper-icon-button-light" class="btnSelectView autoSize" title="${ButtonSelectView}"><span class="material-icons view_comfy"></span></button> <button is="paper-icon-button-light" class="btnSort autoSize" title="${Sort}"><span class="material-icons sort_by_alpha"></span></button>      <button is="paper-icon-button-light" class="btnFilter autoSize" title="${Filter}"><span class="material-icons filter_list"></span></button> </div>
    <div class="alphaPicker alphaPicker-fixed alphaPicker-vertical"> </div>
    <div is="emby-itemscontainer" class="itemsContainer padded-left padded-right"> </div>
    <div class="flex align-items-center justify-content-center flex-wrap-wrap padded-top padded-left padded-right padded-bottom">
      <div class="paging"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pageTabContent" id="suggestionsTab" data-index="1">
    <div id="resumableSection" class="verticalSection hide">
      <div class="sectionTitleContainer sectionTitleContainer-cards">
        <h2 class="sectionTitle sectionTitle-cards padded-left">${HeaderContinueWatching}</h2>
      </div>
      <div is="emby-itemscontainer" id="resumableItems" class="itemsContainer padded-left padded-right"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="verticalSection">
      <div class="sectionTitleContainer sectionTitleContainer-cards">
        <h2 class="sectionTitle sectionTitle-cards padded-left">${HeaderLatestMovies}</h2>
      </div>
      <div is="emby-itemscontainer" id="recentlyAddedItems" class="itemsContainer padded-left padded-right"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="recommendations"> </div>
    <div class="noItemsMessage hide padded-left padded-right"> <br/>
      <p>${MessageNoMovieSuggestionsAvailable}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pageTabContent" id="trailersTab" data-index="2">
    <div class="flex align-items-center justify-content-center flex-wrap-wrap padded-top padded-left padded-right padded-bottom">
      <div class="paging"></div> <button is="paper-icon-button-light" class="btnSort autoSize" title="${Sort}"><span class="material-icons sort_by_alpha"></span></button> <button is="paper-icon-button-light" class="btnFilter autoSize" title="${Filter}"><span class="material-icons filter_list"></span></button>      </div>
    <div class="alphaPicker alphaPicker-fixed alphaPicker-fixed-right alphaPicker-vertical"> </div>
    <div is="emby-itemscontainer" class="itemsContainer vertical-wrap padded-left padded-right"> </div>
    <div class="flex align-items-center justify-content-center flex-wrap-wrap padded-top padded-left padded-right padded-bottom">
      <div class="paging"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pageTabContent" id="favoritesTab" data-index="3">
    <div class="flex align-items-center justify-content-center flex-wrap-wrap padded-top padded-left padded-right padded-bottom">
      <div class="paging"></div> <button is="paper-icon-button-light" class="btnSelectView autoSize" title="${ButtonSelectView}"><span class="material-icons view_comfy"></span></button> </div>
    <div is="emby-itemscontainer" class="itemsContainer padded-left padded-right">
    </div>
    <div class="flex align-items-center justify-content-center flex-wrap-wrap padded-top padded-left padded-right padded-bottom">
      <div class="paging"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pageTabContent" id="collectionsTab" data-index="4">
    <div class="flex align-items-center justify-content-center flex-wrap-wrap padded-top padded-left padded-right padded-bottom">
      <div class="paging"></div> <button is="paper-icon-button-light" class="btnSelectView autoSize" title="${ButtonSelectView}"><span class="material-icons view_comfy"></span></button> <button is="paper-icon-button-light" class="btnSort autoSize" title="${Sort}"><span class="material-icons sort_by_alpha"></span></button>      <button type="button" is="paper-icon-button-light" class="btnNewCollection autoSize"><span class="material-icons add"></span></button> </div>
    <div is="emby-itemscontainer" class="itemsContainer vertical-wrap centered padded-left padded-right" style="text-align:center">
    </div>
    <div class="flex align-items-center justify-content-center flex-wrap-wrap padded-top padded-left padded-right padded-bottom">
      <div class="paging"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pageTabContent" id="genresTab" data-index="5">
    <div id="items"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is hide the trailersTab i tried the following and it did not work

```
#trailersTab {
  display: none !important;
}


/*also tried*/

#moviesPage body>div.skinHeader.focuscontainer-x.skinHeader-withBackground.skinHeader-blurred>div.headerTabs.sectionTabs>div>div>button:nth-child(3) {
  display: none !important
}
```

but they did not work the only part that I could get to work was the following

```
body>div.skinHeader.focuscontainer-x.skinHeader-withBackground.skinHeader-blurred>div.headerTabs.sectionTabs>div>div>button:nth-child(3) {
  display: none !important
}
```

however the above example hides the 3rd button on each page instead of just the movies page

Comment: What's jellyfin?

Comment: I'm assuming there's something more to this jellyfin thing. If you take your basic html there and add the css to display none, it works.

Comment: Probably you should declare a more precise selector.  Please take a look here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp at "How to Calculate Specificity?". For sure there is something more which override your display: none ;)

Comment: the first one should work, not sure why you thought `#moviesPage body` would.. but try `.pageTabContent[data-index="2"]{..}`

Comment: @j08691 jellyfin is a fork of emby and is a media server. the only change i can think of with jellyfin interfering with the html is because it renders the html from inside a javascript file?

Comment: You can use your browser dev tools on inspect to see exactly who/where the CSS is getting overridden.